# How to find the maximum value in a row in plpgsql?

Tags: postgresql, max, row

I am having the following table

| Student Id | Subject A | Subject B | Subject C | Subject D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 98 | 87 | 76 | 100 |
| 2 | 90 | 100 | 64 | 71 |

This table contains information about the marks scored by students in various subject.

Now I need to find the maximum mark scored by each student among the various subject

I need the output to be like

| Student Id | Subjects | Maximum Mark |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Subject D | 100 |
| 2 | Subject B | 100 |

Comment: You shouldn't have one column for each subject. That is bad database design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would need a [lateral join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-a-lateral-join-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql) with the list of subject/mark from the corresponding columns. This works for any number of `Subject X` columns.

```sql
select ext."Student Id", l.* 
from the_table ext, lateral
(
   select l.key, l.value::numeric 
   from the_table t, lateral json_each_text(to_json(t)) l(key, value)
   where "Student Id" = ext."Student Id" and l.key like 'Subject%'
   order by l.value::numeric desc limit 1
) l;
```

DB-Fiddle [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ktpgCoDZ72s6BQWa91cdW2/0)